# Should there be a way to expand upon why an edit has been rejected rather than just a boilerplate response?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

This has been beaten to death in the comments of other topics, but I was unable to find a topic specifically about **editing** the titles of others and why some get rejected. I was wondering why some of my edits have received the occasional reject despite being approved in the end. This led me to wonder if there was an actual benefit to re-wording titles, if I was doing something wrong, or if some people tend to reject most suggestions due to the ease of selecting a boilerplate rejection response without having to explain why nor aid in improving edit culture throughout the community.

When reading what other people say about reviewing edits and keeping in mind Stack Overflow's [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) guidelines, it is in my opinion that edits that help clarify the goal, however small those edits may be, are worthwhile. That said, making edits solely for the purpose of farming rep is detrimental to the community as a whole and, with that in mind, it is my opinion that rejections should include organic responses rather than just boilerplate responses as organic responses can help editors improve their editing skills while boilerplate responses provide no opportunity for learning from one's mistakes.

Comment: [As far as I can see](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7307119/avengefulghost?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you have no rejected edit suggestions on SO, for titles or otherwise. Do you have some examples to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Whups. Didn't notice I was in the answer box. I'll update it.

Comment: *if some people tend to reject most suggestions due to the ease of selecting a boilerplate rejection response* - This doesn't make sense to me. Are you asking if rejecting an edit is easier than just accepting it?

Comment: > This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability

Comment: but... how is clicking "reject" then choosing that as a boilerplate answer HARDER than "accept"?

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be best to offer a personal reason why the edit was rejected so as to improve the editing culture

Comment: @avengefulghost you ARE aware a lot of people will just write gibberish? Anyway, whenever I rejected edits, the boilerplate answer fit my needs. Why should I write my own if the boilerplate answer is the one I want? Should I manually type in the boilerplate?

Comment: If this is implemented, people should be forced to add "organic responses" to their acceptance of edits as well... to help editors improve their editing skills.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but there I would accept ONE boilerplate for "accepting", namely : "I dunno what I am doing, just clicking accept to get a badge"

Comment: It makes sense not to waste time on utterly poor edits and a boilerplate works just fine, but for edits that have potential, wouldn't it make sense to help those editors improve?

Comment: @avengefulghost so how do you make the distinction? If the system can't differentiate between the two, you are forcing EVERYONE to type for EVERY edit they reject, whether it's a potentially good one or not.

Comment: Won't removing the boilerplate imply that reviewers can reject for whatever reason they want, rather than a limited list of reasons?

Comment: That's a great idea @MikeMcCaughan !

Comment: I don't suggest removing the boilerplate, but rather including an option to expand on the rejection or approval

Comment: @avengefulghost Maybe clarify that in your post? Because " it is my opinion that rejections should include organic responses rather than boilerplate " I interpret as "no more boilerplates" (and while I don't necessarily think it's needed.... I wouldn't fight it, as opposed to "no more boilerplates")

Comment: "should include" translates to get rid of?

Comment: If this question is primarily about comments on edit reviews, you should edit its title to match it.

Comment: @avengefulghost "rather than" is pretty unequivocal actually. If you meant "should include organic responses ALONGSIDE boilerplate", then it would have been clearer.

Comment: @duplode Irony abounds lol. I'll do that

Comment: @Patrice ah, I left out 'just'. It should have read "rather than just boilerplate". My mistake

Comment: @avengefulghost ^^ No worries. that's why we can edit ;) And as I said, I will not fight against that proposal lol. I have no particular wish to see it done, but I don't think it'll hurt the site either :). Completely opposed to how I see "0 boilerplate"(also why my downvote disappeared). Good luck with this proposal then :)

Comment: @Patrice lol considering how many edits occur, I can't blame you for not wanting an option like that, and I appreciate your participation in this!

Comment: @avengefulghost I still think you should pass some example what is not clear in boiler plate, maybe *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible"*, which often translate in to some user thinking that your edit was not significant enough.

Comment: _"I don't suggest removing the boilerplate, but rather including an option to expand on the rejection or approval"_. For rejecting an edit, there is already a Causes Harm option where the reviewer can enter any custom reason they want (up to 100 chars, or so). For accepts, I personally don't think this would be very useful. Is the Accept itself not enough feedback?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I understand that, but the boilerplate rejection doesn't explain why. Would it not be beneficial to help potentially good edits rather than lump them all in with the awful or superfluous?

Comment: @PetterFriberg or even just to dissuade people from making poor edits by making then aware of what it is that's resulting in a rejection

Comment: @avengefulghost I think you overestimate how much most people will either know that their edits are rejected or care why their edits are rejected.

Comment: @Servy that's fair, true and unfortunate

Comment: @Servy @Patrice In line with what @NathanTuggy said in the answer, @EnriMR left the rejection `This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.` and they were absolutely right. The edit I made DID deviate, so I updated it and it was accepted.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I clearly didn't understand what you had said. You were right on the mark. Thanks for your assistance and my apologies!

Comment: @avengefulghost this is a good example http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14654609, the community is basically stating that you are on the limit of what is a significant edit, note it was also report in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34708670#34708670

Comment: @avengefulghost as you seem to really want to learn the site: multiple @s don't ping beyond the first:) (i just happened to look back at thos as I am nosy). Also you can't ping someone not already on the comment thread (like Nathan and Enri, for instance)

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks! That chat helped a lot! I didn't know I could find chats like that. I'm going to research how I can find those chats now lol

Comment: @Patrice Thanks! Is there a way I can give reputation points to all you wonderful teachers?

Comment: @avengefulghost not on meta, and not only through comments. The only thing you could do (please don't do it though) is to go through profiles and then upvote content. I say don't do it because it's frowned upon:you should upvote based on the content not the person. In any case I know I don't do this for rep. Just happy to see someone genuinely trying to understand Stack. Quite refreshing, to be honest. The next best thing you CAN do is help make this community a great one by providing good content/moderating.

Comment: @Patrice sold! :D

Comment: and last thing do not worry about downvotes on meta, they are different then main, it's just people stating if they agree or disagree with your suggestion (not whether your "question" is good or not).

Comment: +1 to Petter's comment. I originally downvoted the question as I disagreed with the suggestion. The question itself (and your overall stance) deserves praise :p. We need more new users like you!

Comment: @PetterFriberg lol thanks :) it's almost as if you read my mind...or did you? Dun dun duuuuuun lol

Comment: @Patrice Thank you! I love to learn and improve and just as I should learn the language and rules of another country I'm travelling to, so to should I observe, understand, respect and abide by the rules of this community :D

Comment: @avengefulghost 100% with you there. Alas, most users differ from you :/. My last piece of advice is to remember the VAST majority of users are not like you... Which means that a big portion of meta stack lurkers can be snarky and sometimes curt as we see too many users who do not care. So whenever you see someone being too curt, remember that it's likely someone assumed you were the normal, pushback-y, "i dont care for your site just answer my question" new user :/. You definitely are NOT :). And btw... Welcome to Stack:)

Comment: @PetterFriberg It took some digging, and without that transcript you provided, it would have been a long time before I came across the SO Close chat room. Thanks again!

Comment: @Patrice Thanks! I'm glad to be here and collaborating with awesome people like yourself! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There already is a way to do this. It doesn't see too much use, but it's right there in the list with the boilerplate options. For example, [this rejection](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10625845) uses it to (try to) teach the user not to misuse back-ticks this way, and [this one](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10618529) rails against non-descriptive summaries. And [this edit](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10618126) got not one but two custom rejections.

Usually, though, the boilerplate options, which *are* selected to cover the majority of cases, *do* cover the case well enough that nothing more is needed, except maybe poking around on Meta to see what's up with that.

[image: Screenshot of reason list]